# How to get right values from requirements in Conan recipe to be used as CMake parameters?

Tags: c, cmake, conan, rabbitmq-c

I'm writing recipe for creating package for [rabbitmq-c](https://github.com/alanxz/rabbitmq-c) library. When **ENABLE_SSL_SUPPORT** option in its **CMake** script is checked it requires **OpenSSL** library for its build.

[image: RabbitMQ C client library CMake GUI screen]

As it shown on provided screen paths to **Debug** and **Release** versions of **libeay.lib** and **ssleay.lib** files are required.

In my `conanfile.py` for `rabbitmq-c` library I have the following code which describes the dependency.

```
def requirements(self):
    if self.options.ssl_support:
        self.requires("OpenSSL/1.0.2l@bobeff/stable")
```

How to get right values from required **OpenSSL** package to set them in **CMake** configure options for **RabbitMQ-C** recipe?

The package `OpenSSL/1.0.2l@bobeff/stable` can be build with different settings and options. How to choose which to be used when I'm building **RabbitMQ-C**? For example how to choose whether static or dynamic version of **OpenSSL** to be used for linking with **RabbitMQ-C** *dll* files?

Comment: If you mean, how to access the dependencies model, from the consumer recipe (RabbitMQ) you can access it via ``self.deps_cpp_info["OpenSSL"]``.  And that object will contain information for ``include_paths``, ``lib_paths``, etc. You can check: http://conanio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integrations/other.html. Please tell me if this makes sense, and I will elaborate an extended answer

Comment: @drodri +1 10x It makes perfect sense, but in addition here two different OpenSSL packages are required. One for Debug, and one for Release. Now I'm creating different packages for Debug and Release variants of RabbitMQ-C and because of this I can use the same value, but how to handle this if I was going to create one package for both debug and release versions of RabbitMQ-C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have full access to the dependencies model inside your `build()` method, so you can access:

```
def build(self):
    print(self.deps_cpp_info["OpenSSL"].rootpath)
    print(self.deps_cpp_info["OpenSSL"].include_paths)
    print(self.deps_cpp_info["OpenSSL"].lib_paths)
    print(self.deps_cpp_info["OpenSSL"].bin_paths)
    print(self.deps_cpp_info["OpenSSL"].libs)
    print(self.deps_cpp_info["OpenSSL"].defines)
    print(self.deps_cpp_info["OpenSSL"].cflags)
    print(self.deps_cpp_info["OpenSSL"].cppflags)
    print(self.deps_cpp_info["OpenSSL"].sharedlinkflags)
    print(self.deps_cpp_info["OpenSSL"].exelinkflags)
```

Also if you want to access the aggregated values (for all the dependencies/requirements), you can do:

```
def build(self):
   print(self.deps_cpp_info.include_paths)
   print(self.deps_cpp_info.lib_paths)
   ...
```

So, given those values, you can pass them to your build system, in the case of CMake you could do something like:

```
def build(self):
    cmake = CMake(self)
    # Assuming there is only 1 include path, otherwise, we could join it
    cmake.definitions["SSL_INCLUDE_PATH"] = self.deps_cpp_info["OpenSSL"].include_paths[0]
```

That will be translated to a cmake command including the `-DSSL_INCLUDE_PATH=<path to openssl include>` flag.

If you go for multi-configuration packages, you can check (http://docs.conan.io/en/latest/packaging/package_info.html#multi-configuration-packages). They will define `debug, release` configs, that you can also later use in your model:

```
def build(self):
    # besides the above values, that will contain data for both configs
    # you can access information specific for each configuration
    print(self.deps_cpp_info["OpenSSL"].debug.rootpath)
    print(self.deps_cpp_info["OpenSSL"].debug.include_paths)
    ...
    print(self.deps_cpp_info["OpenSSL"].release.rootpath)
    print(self.deps_cpp_info["OpenSSL"].release.include_paths)
    ...
```

Comment: What about if **OpenSSL** is not multi configuration package but in package  recipe which I'm creating I need both Debug and Release versions of **OpenSSL** ?

Comment: That is not possible in the model. Some tricks might be possible, like using the ``cmake_multi`` generator and installing both debug and release dependencies, but that is complex and error prone. So basically, multi-config has to be consistent in the dependency graph, if the package you are building is multi-config, the dependencies have to be multi-config.